# Parsing by inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, xsd

I have some scene hierarchy where nodes inherit from each other in fashion

```
<xs:complexType name="XNode">
    <xs:attribute name="layer" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and

```
<xs:complexType name="XStyleable">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="XNode">
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

where I would like to have

```
<xs:complexType name="XGroup">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="XStyleable">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="XNode" type="XNode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

which will recognize not only XNodes but everything that extends XNode as well, so having structure like

```
<XGroup>
    <XNode/>
    <XGroup/>
    <XNode/>
    <XStyleable/>
</XGroup>
```

will result into instance of XGroup containing list of three instances (two XNode, one XGroup and one XStyleable) in List where I can test each instance on it's original class and decide it's faith after cast.

I know I can do

```
<xs:complexType name="XGroup">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="XStyleable">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="XNode" type="XNode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="XGroup" type="XGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

but that leaves out the information about original order of nodes within parent, which I would like to keep.

Do you have ANY suggestions how to solve this? I really do not fancy idea of writing my own parser just to get this behaviour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

### XML Schema (schema.xsd)

You could leverage substitution groups in your XML Schema and set it up like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="XNode" type="XNode"/>
    <xs:complexType name="XNode">
        <xs:attribute name="layer" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="XStyleable" type="XStyleable" substitutionGroup="XNode"/>
    <xs:complexType name="XStyleable">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="XNode">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute name="class" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="XGroup" type="XGroup" substitutionGroup="XNode"/>
    <xs:complexType name="XGroup">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="XStyleable">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="XNode"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

### Generate the Java Model

Running the following will generate a Java model from the XML Schema.  Since there is no target namespace in the XML Schema the default package name is `generated`.

```
xjc schema.xsd
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import generated.XGroup;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        JAXBElement<XGroup> je = (JAXBElement<XGroup>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XGroup>
    <XNode/>
    <XGroup/>
    <XNode/>
    <XStyleable/>
</XGroup>
```

### For More Information

I have written more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html